# PUT and GET methods with router.put and router.delete not working (express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm building a CRUD app. I'm stuck on update and delete operation, everything else seems to be working. So I use method-override to send PUT and GET request.

Here's the relevant code:

`app.js`

```
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

Here's what I wrote for update and delete. I'm using monk driver for mongodb.

`index.js`

```
var router = express.Router();

router.put('/videos/:id', function(req, res){
    var collection = db.get('videos');
    var item = {
        title: req.body.title,
        genre: req.body.genre,
        image: req.body.image,
        description: req.body.desc
    };
    var id = req.params.id;
    collection.update(
    {_id: id}, {
        $set: item
    });
    res.redirect('/videos');
});

router.delete('/videos/:id', function(req, res){
    var collection = db.get('videos');
    collection.remove({"_id" : req.params.id});
    res.redirect('/videos');
});
```

For delete form

```
<form action="/videos/<%= video._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete video</button>
</form>
```

For update form

```
<form method="POST" action="/videos/<%= video._id %>?_method=PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

I've searched in many places, still get a webpage not found (404) error when I hit the submit button.
What am I missing ?
The submit button should call the two methods I showed in `index.js`.

Comment: What is actually being rendered in the HTML source?

Comment: 404, webpage not found.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about the source of the form.

Comment: The source is a form where the user can enter details which are then out to database.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was hoping you could share the html form

Comment: Its a standard HTML form, when I press the submit button, it goes to /videos/video_id?_method=DELETE, which I think is not being picked up by `index.js` methods.

Comment: I understand that, but as I keep saying.. I think it's helpful to share the actual HTML output in case there's a problem there. Do you want help or not?

Comment: The HTML is exactly same as [this](https://github.com/NikitaVispute/Web-Programming/blob/master/Video%20Web%20Application%20Vidzy/Vidzy/views/edit.ejs), had to add {} in import statements. When I click on submit button, the URL becomes http://localhost:3000/videos/5f9aa2e7ff1ef312a4776bdc?_method=PUT and I get `This localhost page can’t be found`.

Comment: I'm asking for the rendered HTML, not the original source in the template.

Comment: So go to your form in a browser. Press 'view source' or use your developer tools. Copy the HTML source from there. Press 'edit' in stack overflow, and paste the result here too.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you exported the index.js file and imported it into the app.js,
and i think it should work fine but try restarting the server and see if it works. :)

Comment: Did you exported the routes from the index.js and imported in into the app.js file?

Comment: Yes, I do `module.exports = router`.

Answer (score 0):

> The form method and express route doesn't match.

The form method for both are POST respectively.

However if you look at the express routes the method are PUT and DELETE.

Try changing the routes and test again if it works.

Comment: They are sent as POST requests  and method override will cast them as PUT and DELETE requests. That's what I read from method-override docs. I want to delete and put and entry into database. Standard POST request won't be suitable.

Comment: Then i think you should include right tags. People with relevant knowledge could answer this. I don't think so it is node.js or javascript issue. Include the library tag the question

Answer (score 0):

I changed `router.put` and `router.delete` to `router.post`.